# What is the extent of this "invention" clause in this contract?

Tags: contract-law, employment, new-jersey

> **OWNERSHIP OF WORK PRODUCT, IDEAS, INVENTIONS, DISCOVERIES AND TRADEMARKS**
>
> I shall promptly disclose to (COMPANY) all ideas, inventions or
> discoveries, whether or not patentable, which I may conceive or make,
> alone or with others, during my employment, whether or not during
> working hours, and which directly or indirectly:
>
> 1. relate to matters within the scope of my duties or field of responsibility during my employment by (COMPANY); or
> 2. are based on my knowledge of the actual business or the actual or anticipated research and development of (COMPANY); or
> 3. are aided by the use of time, materials, facilities or information of (COMPANY).

[The following paragraphs can be read here. (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/YG92D7Qn)

---

Hello. I hope you can provide some advice on my situation.

This is a part of my employment contract. I have omitted the name of the company. My location is NJ.

I work as a cloud engineer. Recently I've been thinking about a particular app/business idea and I've been putting some time and effort into it outside of work (weekends, or in the evenings during the week).

Since I would eventually like to implement this idea as a website / web application and utilize cloud technology in doing so, could this mean my employer owns the idea and anything I develop --since I would use the same technology for my idea that I do at work? Even though it is completely and utterly unrelated to the business model of my employer and I have not used work hours in my implementation of this idea? Would this also mean that any open-source software I develop outside of work automatically belongs to my employer?

What is the extent and limitations of such a clause, which I have agreed to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> could this mean my employer owns the idea and anything I develop --since I would use the same technology for my idea that I do at work?

No, unless by "technology" you mean the employer's *materials* or resources (see condition 3 of the clause). Your remark that "*this is completely and utterly unrelated to [employer's] business model*" survives items 1 and 2. Likewise, working on your idea *outside hours* survives the corresponding part of item 3.

> Would this also mean that any open-source software I develop outside of work automatically belongs to my employer?

No, unless the software you develop is "*based on [your] knowledge [etc.] of (COMPANY)*".